# Django - NoReverseMatch at

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I am trying to sync two Django projects and am finding myself with the following error:

> Reverse for 'file-add' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

There seems to be a problem now with the template, line 15:

```
5   
6   
7   {% block content %}
8   
9   {% if form.non_field_errors %}
10  <div class="panel">
11    {{ form.non_field_errors }}
12  </div>
13  {% endif %}
14  
15  <form action="{% url 'file-add' %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
16    <fieldset>
17      <legend>Add CV</legend>
18  
19      <div class="large-12 columns">
20        <div class="row" id="file_container">
21          {% if form.f.errors %}
22          <input placeholder="First name" name="f" type="file" id="file" class="error" />
23          {% else %}
24          <label for="f" name="CV" />
25          <input name="f" type="file" id="file" />
```

Since I don't remember changing this template in any way, and all the files should be the same as the ones on my other server, are there any small issues then I am missing?

```
> <form action="{% url 'file-add' %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

**EDIT**

It seems to be something to do with my urls files. I have a main urls file, which forwards anything with the url "/jobs/" to the jobs url file.

```
url(r'^jobs/', include('jobs.urls', namespace="jobs")),
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
url(r'^admin_tools/', include('admin_tools.urls')),
```

The jobs urls file then points to the relevant jobs pages.

```
url(r'^new', views.importDemoData, name='importDemoData'),
url(r'^add', FileAddView.as_view(), name='file-add'),
url(r'^files/list', FileListView.as_view(), name='list'),

# This view lists uploaded files
url(r'^success', FileListView.as_view(), name='home'),
url(r'^(?P<unique_id>\w+)/$', views.application, name='application'),
```

If I move the "file-add" line into the main urls file, it seems to work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to add namespace before the URL name

The Reverse of "jobs/add" will {% url 'jobs:file-add' %} which is {% url 'namespace:name'%}.

When you removed the namespace it worked because the 'jobs/add' url will match with {% url 'file-add' %}

Answer (score 1):

I think you should add namespace front of URL name

Answer (score 0):

If someone could explain this to me that would be great..

I removed the namespace from this line in the main urls file:

```
url(r'^jobs/', include('jobs.urls', namespace="jobs")),
```

changing it to:

```
url(r'^jobs/', include('jobs.urls')),
```

and it worked! This is a little weird as it seems to be working fine like that on my other server..

Answer (score 0):

As they say in their documentation: [url-namespaces-and-included-urlconfs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces-and-included-urlconfs)

> URL namespaces of included URLconfs can be specified in two ways.
>
> Firstly, you can provide the application and instance namespaces as arguments to include() when you construct your URL patterns. For example,:
>
> *url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls', namespace='author-polls', app_name='polls')),*
>
> This will include the URLs defined in polls.urls into the application namespace 'polls', with the instance namespace 'author-polls'.
>
> Secondly, you can include an object that contains embedded namespace data. If you include() a list of url() instances, the URLs contained in that object will be added to the global namespace. However, you can also include() a 3-tuple containing:
>
> `(<list of url() instances>, <application namespace>, <instance namespace>)`